# Swapping array elements in coffeescript

Tags: arrays, string, coffeescript, swap

I'm learning coffeescript and wrote the following function to reverse a given word:

```
reverse = (word) ->
 if word.length is 0
     return "empty string"
 if word.length is 1
     return word
 left = 0
 right = word.length-1
 while left < right
     swap(word, left, right)
     #[word[left], word[right]] = [word[right], word[left]]
     left++
     right--
 return word

swap = (word, left, right) ->
 console.log "#{word[left]} #{word[right]}"
 temp = word[left]
 word[left] = word[right]
 word[right] = temp
 console.log "#{word[left]} #{word[right]}"

console.log reverse("coffeescript")
```

But it doesn't work. In the swap function itself, the characters at the two indices don't switch places. What am I missing?

Comment: My answer does exactly this by using the .split("") to turn the string to a char array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem might be that in Javascript strings are immutable and so you are not allowed to change them.

An alternative approach to reverse a string is

```
 "coffeescript".split("").reverse().join ""
```

From [rosettacode.org](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Reverse_a_string#CoffeeScript).

Comment: argh, can't believe I forgot strings are immutable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One other option for reversing a string is CoffeeScript is:

`(c for c in 'coffeescript' by -1).join ''`